# Homemade photographic emulsion DiY formula / recipe

Tags: diy, art, glass-plate

Does anyone have a photosensitive emulsion recipe that effectively works and personal experience working with it?

Please consider that i have access to lab conditions and some college level experience in chem labs.  I am comfortable with the basic procedures involved and (hopefully) capable of follwoing safety precautions involved.

I want to produce a photosensitive emulsion (silver nitrate + halide, gelatin based) for amateur / artistic prints on materials other than film paper.  I dabbled with this in the 1980s.  In the past i had access to preformulated products but now i dont anymore (noone imports into brazil film products anymore).

NOTE: i appreciate suggestions re lomography, but that technique is not the subject here, though it might achieve similar results in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across various formulae and recipes using silver nitrate and bromides mixed with a gelatin base.  The ones that seem to be most consistent involve potassium bromide and silver nitrate, but recipes or lab techniques vary.

- [Mark Osterman's Dry Plate Emulsion Recipe](http://thelightfarm.com/Map/DryPlate/Osterman/DryPlatePart4.htm)
- [Silver Gelatin Unwashed Emulsion](http://www.handmadefilm.org/resources/technicalResources/processes/emulsionMaking/silverGelatin/silverGelatinEmulsion.html)
- [Simple Silver-Based Photographic Emulsion Suitable for Coating on Glass or Film](http://unblinkingeye.com/Articles/Emulsion/emulsion.html)

*DISCLAIMER: as of this time i have not tried any of these.  as soon as i do, i will update this post, preferably with a complete commented  step by step*